# Using .intersect/.intersectsBox for object collision threeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js, collision-detection, intersection, bounding-box

Hi I am working on a basic breakout/arkanoid game in threeJS. Right now all I have is a paddle and a ball that bounces around the screen. I am trying to get collision working so that when the ball hits the paddle it bounces away. I've been trying to using bounding boxes to accomplish this however I am running into an issue where the .intersect/.intersectsBox are not properly registering an intersection and I don't know why. Below is the code I have so far -

```
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(5, 1, 1);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
var cubeBoxHelper = new THREE.BoxHelper(cube, 0xff0000);
var boundingBoxPaddle = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(cubeBoxHelper);
cubeBoxHelper.update();

const geometrySphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 32, 32);
const materialSphere = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffff00 });
const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometrySphere, materialSphere);
var sphereBoxHelper = new THREE.BoxHelper(sphere, 0xff0000);
var boundingBoxBall = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(sphereBoxHelper);
sphereBoxHelper.update();

scene.add(cube, cubeBoxHelper, sphere, sphereBoxHelper);

sphere.position.y = 5;
camera.position.z = 15;
camera.position.y = 10;

var xSpeed = 0.0005;
var dx = 0.1;
var dy = 0.1;

function bounce()
{
    if (sphere.position.x < -19 || sphere.position.x > 18.5)
    {
        dx = -dx;
    }
    if (sphere.position.y < -5 || sphere.position.y > 19)
    {
        dy = -dy;
    }
    sphere.position.x += dx;
    sphere.position.y += dy;
    sphereBoxHelper.update();
}

function intersect()
{
    if (boundingBoxBall.intersect(boundingBoxPaddle) == true)
    {
        console.log("intersection");
    }
}

const animate = function ()
{
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    document.addEventListener("keydown", onDocumentKeyDown, false);
    function onDocumentKeyDown(event)
    {
        var keyCode = event.which;
        if (keyCode == 65 && cube.position.x >= -18.5)
        {
            cube.position.x -= xSpeed;
        }
        else if (keyCode == 68 && cube.position.x <= 18)
        {
            cube.position.x += xSpeed;
        }
        cubeBoxHelper.update();
    };
    bounce();
    intersect();
    sphereBoxHelper.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

animate();
```

Right now I have set it so the intersect function just logs to the console so I can tell what's happening. Any help would be great as I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

[`Box3.intersect`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Box3.intersect)

> .intersect ( box : Box3 ) : this
> box - Box to intersect with.
>
> Computes the intersection of this and box, setting the upper bound of this box to the lesser of the two boxes' upper bounds and the lower bound of this box to the greater of the two boxes' lower bounds. If there's no overlap, makes this box empty.

What this function is actually doing is updating `boundingBoxBall` with information from `boundingBoxPaddle`, and possibly even setting `boundingBoxBall` to be an empty box!

I think the function you're really after is:

[`Box3.intersectsBox`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Box3.intersectsBox)

> .intersectsBox ( box : Box3 ) : Boolean
> box - Box to check for intersection against.
>
> Determines whether or not this box intersects box.

The `intersectsBox` function returns a simple `true`/`false`, so you can tell if the two boxes have collided.

Also note that your bounding box is relative to the associated geometry. If your transform the `Mesh`, then you will also need to transform the bounding box. The example code on the [`Box3 docs`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Box3) actually highlights this:

```js
const box = new THREE.Box3();

// ...

// in the animation loop, compute the current bounding box with the world matrix
box.copy( mesh.geometry.boundingBox ).applyMatrix4( mesh.matrixWorld );
```

### Full Example:

```js
let W = window.innerWidth;
let H = window.innerHeight;

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true,
  alpha: true
});
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(28, 1, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 50);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
scene.add(camera);

const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.position.set(0, 0, -1);
camera.add(light);

let geo = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(5, 5, 5);
geo.computeBoundingBox();
let mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  color: "red"
});
const left = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);
left.position.set(-15, 0, 0)
scene.add(left);
const right = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);
right.position.set(15, 0, 0)
scene.add(right);

geo = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(1, 16, 16);
geo.computeBoundingBox();
mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  color: "yellow"
});
const ball = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);
scene.add(ball);

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function resize() {
  W = window.innerWidth;
  H = window.innerHeight;
  renderer.setSize(W, H);
  camera.aspect = W / H;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  render();
}

let rate = 0.1;
let goingRight = true;
let ballBox = new THREE.Box3();
let wallBox = new THREE.Box3();

function animate() {
  render();

  ball.position.x += ((goingRight) ? 1 : -1) * rate;
  ball.updateMatrix();
  ball.updateMatrixWorld(true);

  ballBox.copy(ball.geometry.boundingBox);
  ballBox.applyMatrix4(ball.matrixWorld);

  if (goingRight) {
    wallBox.copy(right.geometry.boundingBox);
    wallBox.applyMatrix4(right.matrixWorld);
    if (ballBox.intersectsBox(wallBox)) {
      goingRight = false;
    }
  } else {
    wallBox.copy(left.geometry.boundingBox);
    wallBox.applyMatrix4(left.matrixWorld);
    if (ballBox.intersectsBox(wallBox)) {
      goingRight = true;
    }
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

window.addEventListener("resize", resize);

resize();
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The issue that I'm still running into is even if I use .intersectsBox instead it continues to constantly log intersection to the console even if the to bounding boxes aren't intersecting at all.

Comment: @OliverCollier I added some more info that might be helpful. Your bounding boxes are local to their shapes, so you have to update them to match the current spatial orientation of the shape.

Comment: Tried your suggestion and no luck. Even when the bounding boxes are completely seperate it still continually logs intersect. I have no idea what I've done wrong here

Comment: @OliverCollier I have added a full, run-able example of a ball bouncing between two boxes by watching for bounding box intersections. If you continue to have problems after reviewing the logic here, please update your question with your updated code so we can see what might be going wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try